# How to retrieve unique groups and their count?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a csv below.

```
UID CID
u-1 c-1
u-1 c-2
u-1 c-3
u-2 c-2
u-2 c-1
u-2 c-3
u-3 c-3
u-3 c-2
u-3 c-2
```

I want unique group count.

```
ex) c-1, c-2, c-3 is one
    c-2, c-1, c-3 is two
    c-3, 3-2, c-1 is three
    c-1, c-2, c-3 is already group
thus, unique group count is 3.
```

CID are many count. of couse, UID..

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby('UID')['CID'].nunique()` ?

Comment: Try this - `df.groupby('UID').CID.apply(frozenset).value_counts().size`

Comment: If I have [u1 - c1, u1 - c1, u2 - c1], should there be one unique group or two? Since in u1 and u2's case, only id is c1.

Comment: Also, why do you mention `c-1, c-2, c-3 is already group`? I don't see a `u-4` in your question.